# Extract annotation parameters from a bean/class

Tags: java, rest, annotations, jersey, jackson

I am using the `@JsonProperty(name = "property_name")` (Jackson) annotation wherever the property name in the json is different from the property name in my object. Is there a way I can programmatically access this information somewhere else in code?

Example:

```
public class Entity {

    protected long entityName;

    @JsonProperty("entity_name")
    public long getEntityName() {
        return entityName;
    }

    public void setEntityName(String entityName) {
        this.entityName = entityName;
    }
}
```

What I need is a method to map entity_name to entityName. e.g, `getActualFieldName("entity_name")` should return `"entityName"`. I can keep a separate file with all these mappings, but I don't want to do that because this information is already present in the form of `@JsonProperty` annotations. If I can extract it from there somehow, it would simplify things a bit.

Comment: You want the annotation to change? Might be helpful to show a before and after of what you want because I'm not exactly sure of what you're asking.

Comment: added an example. Does this clarify it? I don't want to change anything, I just want the annotated property value.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/GetAnnotationParameter.htm) Helper utility. getAnnotationParameter